# Dynamic SLD Name and Title using Geosever

Tags: dynamic, openlayers, geoserver, sld

We are trying to make dynamic sld where color pallets will be created according to env parameter passed to sld, and get Legend for the same using `getLegendGraphichs` of geoserver but with no success, is it possible to get `Name and Title` section of sld also get updated dynamically according to env parameters,
if not is there other alternatives?

[image]

Our thought is that if some how we are passing env parameter to `title` then we will  get the updated title of `legend`

This the `env` string we are passing to openlayers wms request
`ENV=class1:38.81;class2:42.82;class3:46.82;class4:50.83;class5:54.83;class6:58.84;class7:62.84`

```css
<se:Rule>
  <se:Name>0.1 - 
     <!-- "2nd Name should be taken from env parameter" -->
      <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>class1</ogc:Literal>
        <!-- "below line for default one" -->
        <ogc:Literal>48.78</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>
  </se:Name>
  <se:Description>
    <se:Title> 0.1 - 
     <!-- "2nd Title should be taken from env parameter" -->
      <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>class1</ogc:Literal>
        <!-- "below line for default one" -->
        <ogc:Literal>48.78</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>            
    </se:Title>
  </se:Description>
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        <ogc:PropertyName>wght_indx</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>wght_indx</ogc:PropertyName>
        <!-- "This is working when we pass env parameter" -->
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>class1</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>48.78</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    <se:Fill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ade6ce</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Fill>
    <se:Stroke>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Stroke>
  </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
</se:Rule>
```

Comment: I don't believe that is currently possible, but you could add sone code to do it

Comment: @IanTurton could you please share some code or reference so it will be easy for us to understand

Comment: I'd start with https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/fb441eefa631a2f66b31b62c6811e44517493b2c/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/LegendUtils.java#L861 which might just need to evaluate the expression, or you may need to work back to where the SLD is parsed to make sure it is expecting an `Expression` and not just a string literal.

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton, can you please edit the code which i shared, so I can understand it better

Comment: I see no code?? Currently, in your SLD you are using an expression (`ogc:Function name="env"`) while the code I linked to is only expecting a string (in line with the SLD specification) so it doesn't work. You (or [someone else](https://geoserver.org/support/)) will need to modify that code (and have the change accepted by the GeoServer community) so that it evaluates the expression to create the title text.